# how to check if unique_ptr points to this

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, this, unique-ptr

In following peace of code, I'm trying to find another object that has the same coordinates as `this`. How to do it correctly?

```
        auto& organism_vector = world->get_vector();
        auto attacked_organism = find_if(begin(organism_vector), end(organism_vector), [this](const unique_ptr<Organism>& attacked_organism)
            {
                return this->get_coordinates() == attacked_organism->get_coordinates() && *this != *attacked_organism;
            });
```

Another thing, when I finally manage to get this iterator, how to refer to attacked_organism class methods?

```
*attacked_organism.get_coordinates();
```

Comment: Iterators in in many cases can be used like pointers. Depending on operator types some operations are unavailable, but in general increment(`++`), dereferencing(unary `*`) and arrow operator are available as wall as (in)equality checks (`==`, `!=`; those compare the positions though, not the objects at those positions). Especially the following loop should work with pointers replaced with iterators for every iterator type: `int array[10] {...}; auto pos = std::begin(array); auto const end = std::end(array); while (pos != end) { std::cout << *array << '\n'; ++pos; }`

Comment: In your last code snippet the `*` operator is applied ***after*** the `.` operator because of operator precedence, making the expression invalid. Furthermore you've got a iterator for a unique_ptr, so that's another level to dereference: `(**attacked_organism).get_coordinates();` (the type of `*attacked_organism` is `std::unique_ptr<Organism>&` and dereferencing again you've got an expression of type `Organism&` that can be used with the `.` operator)

Comment: @fabian what if i wanted to use -> operator?

Comment: You can use it on an expression of type `std::unique_ptr<Organism>&`: `(*attacked_organism)->get_coordinates();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `*this != *attacked_organism` to `this != attacked_organism.get()`:

```cpp
auto& organism_vector = world->get_vector();
auto attacked_organism = find_if(begin(organism_vector), end(organism_vector),
    [this](const unique_ptr<Organism>& attacked_organism)
    {
        return this->get_coordinates() == attacked_organism->get_coordinates() && this != attacked_organism.get();
    }
);
```

Once you have the `iterator` that `find_if()` returns (and after you validate that it is not the `end` iterator), you can call methods on the `Organism` by first dereferencing the iterator to access the `unique_ptr` that is holding the `Organism*` pointer, and then dereferencing the `unique_ptr` to access the `Organism` itself:

```cpp
auto attacked_organism = find_if(...);
if (attacked_organism != end(organism_vector))
{
    (**attacked_organism).get_coordinates();
    or:
    (*attacked_organism)->get_coordinates();
    ...
}
```

---

On a side note: I would not recommend giving your iterator variable the same name as the lambda parameter.  That just makes things confusing to read.  The lambda is trying to find an `Organism` to attack, but it hasn't actually been attacked yet, so you should name the lambda parameter more appropriately, eg:

```cpp
auto attacked_organism = find_if(begin(organism_vector), end(organism_vector),
    [this](const unique_ptr<Organism>& candidate_organism)
    {
        return this->get_coordinates() == candidate_organism->get_coordinates() && this != candidate_organism.get();
    }
);
```

For that matter, I wouldn't really suggest naming the iterator as `attacked_organism`, either.  It is not the actual `Organism`, it is an `iterator` to the `Organism`, so something more like this would be more readable:

```cpp
auto& organism_vector = world->get_vector();
auto found_iterator = find_if(begin(organism_vector), end(organism_vector),
    [this](const unique_ptr<Organism>& candidate_organism)
    {
        return this->get_coordinates() == candidate_organism->get_coordinates() && this != candidate_organism.get();
    }
);
if (found_iterator != end(organism_vector))
{
    auto &attacked_organism = *found_iterator;
    attacked_organism->get_coordinates();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please check my modification as there is one more thing I don't get

Comment: @MichałTurek updated